# Laptop shutsdown after wakeup from sleep

Tags: debian, kde, suspend

I'm using Acer Aspire V5-131 running Debian 11 with KDE.
Sometimes after waking up from sleep it shows blank screen and shuts down immediately.
How I can get logs and find out the source of problem?

I used this laptop before on Ubuntu and had same problem, but on KDE neon all was alright.

When I wake it from sleep, the laptop is fully charged. It happens no matter which power source is used.

Answer (score 1):

Check journalctl but tell it you want the logs from the previous boot

```
journalctl --boot=-1
```

Comment: I thoroughly disagree.
They specifically asked "How I can get logs and find out the source of problem?"

I answered the actual question

Comment: I agree that the OP asked "How I can get logs", but the key part of the question is still "find out the source of problem", to which I can find no indications in your answer, hence my comment. But it's only my opinion and others obviously think otherwise, so I'm fine with that.